# Update 500 tables with SSDT on VS2017 for SQL Server 2016

Tags: visual-studio-2017, sql-server-2016, sql-server-data-tools

I am working on a SSDT database project using VS2017 and SQL Server 2016. I need to change all the table columns with a `char` datatype to `nvarchar`.

Similarly for `varchar` to `nvarchar` and `text` to `nvarchar`, and `smallint` to `int` datatype.

I have 500 tables in the tables folder. What would be the best way to replace/update these columns?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure that there is BEST way to do that, however this is what would I do (note that spacing and brackets are important in the text search):

1. Replace all text in the solution " CHAR(" to " NCHAR("
2. " VARCHAR(" to " NVARCHAR("
3. " TEXT" to " NVARCHAR(MAX)" --> note that this one is quite dangerous, you need to verify manually that all the changes are ok
4. " SMALLINT" to " INT"

When you did that, build the project and fix errors.

However I can understand why do you switch to UNICODE, but converting all SMALLINTs to INTs system-wide is quite a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What do you also recommend if the conversion only for Tables not for the entire project, I don't think VS2017 with SSDT has folder only options. Let me know if I am missing anything here. thanks.

Comment: You can use sublime_text or notepad++ or any other powerful text editor. I'll give an example on sublime_text. Search across all files (ctrl+shift+F). There you have possibility to choose the only folders you are looking in. So, grab all the folders with tables (I hope that you have different folders for tables) and replace using these folders.

Comment: Wow fantastic thanks a ton, downloaded sublime_Text . finished my job in 10mins